# query On click event won't return firing context

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Im transferring my web app to Bootstrap but i encountered the next issue.

the on('click') events won't pass any context nor event source to the firing function.

```
$('#'+target+'_HID.box.flipped:visible a').click(function(e){
        console.log('otroclick',e,this)
    })
```

this fires the console.log message but e and this cames empty and before button bootstrap the events came fairly normal.
before the links they were buttons but the same happened.

Comment: it's quite strange! Any chance you replicate issue on jsfiddle?

Comment: i was following the bootstrap 3 manual and in the examples the code markup tells to add a 'type="button"' attribute to the button. i removed this and the event handler worked again. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons sorry for bothering you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want the `this` value in the handler to be the same as the `this` value of the code that sets up the event?  If so, you can achieve this easily with `bind`.  Bind allows you to pre-set the `this` value of a function (and also, optionally curry parameters).

```
$('#'+target+'_HID.box.flipped:visible a').click(function(e){
        console.log('otroclick',e,this)
}.bind(this));
```

This will set the `this` value of the handler to the current `this` value.

And like all nice things, `bind` isn't supported in IE8, so you'll want to grab a shim from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) if you need to support that pile.

Comment: how could you use .bind() to set context to clicked element? I guess OP wants 'this' to refer to the clicked element or maybe i just don't understand his issue

Comment: @A.Wolff - the this value will already refer to the clicked element.  Unless *I* misunderstood OP.

Comment: i want this to be the firing element(the button) the problem was with the button markup that I copied from bootstrap 3. thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is working fine, I have tested this

```
$( "#target" ).click({a:5}, function(evt) {
  console.log( "------------" );
  console.log( this, evt );
  console.log( evt.data );
});
```

you can check it on
http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

you may need to update jquery

Comment: was version 1.10 but the problem was with the markup in the button. thanks